# How can I solve this codewars kata. (really simple) Ruby

Tags: ruby

The instructions:

You have to write a method, that return the length of the missing array.

Example:

```
 [[1, 2], [4, 5, 1, 1], [1], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] --> 3
```

If the array of arrays is null/nil or empty, the method should return 0.

When an array in the array is null or empty, the method should return 0 too!
There will always be a missing element and its length will be always between the given arrays.

If you do array_of_arrays.sort_by! {|x| x.size} you'll get this:
 `[[1], [1, 2], [4, 5, 1, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]` it's missing an array with three elements inside the main array.

Also the def name: def getLengthOfMissingArray(array_of_arrays)

Comment: What do you mean by "missing array"?

Comment: If you do array_of_arrays.sort_by! {|x| x.size} you'll get this:
``` [[1], [1, 2], [4, 5, 1, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]``` it's missing an array with three elements inside the main array.

Comment: So you don't care about the contents of the arrays, just their length? `aa.map(&:length).sort` and then look for gaps? This is where `take_while` comes in handy.

Comment: @taddman exactly. Just their length. Nothing else.

Comment: The problem is not clear. Please edit to provide the link to Codewar's statement of the problem. If this is a homework problem SO's policy is that you should explain (in your question) the efforts have you made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: "How can I solve this codewars kata." – Writing some code would be a good way to start, I think. When you run into problems with the code, write tests, run it in a debugger and trace the execution and carefully check the value and type of every variable at every step, "run" it with pen and paper and trace the execution and carefully check the value and type of every variable at every step, carefully study the documentation of every single method, module, class, and library you are using, just ignore it for a week, and then start from scratch with a fresh mind and fresh eyes.

Comment: And if you *still* have problems after doing all that, construct a [mre] and ask a precise and focused question on [so].

Answer (score 2):

```rb
a = [[1, 2], [4, 5, 1, 1], [1], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

new_arr = a.map(&:length)

missing_num_arr = (new_arr.min..new_arr.max).to_a - new_arr
# => [3]
```

1. You can map given array by length
2. Take minimum & maximum from mapped array
3. Create new array from minimum & maximum and subtract mapped array
4. You will get result